# Flex-item button not vertically stretching in old Chrome versions

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox, browserstack

Here's my problem : I'm testing an app in old browsers with BrowserStack, and I'm having a problem with Chrome 30 and a flex-item button, which doesn't want to stretch vertically. Haven't heard or read anything abount that particular Flexbox issue.

Not really a big deal, but visually quite disturbing. Here's the code :

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

nav>img {
  align-self: flex-end;
  width: 15rem;
  min-width: 20%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 2rem .5rem .5rem;
}

nav>div {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 2rem;
}

nav>div>* {
  font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}

nav button {
  flex: 1;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #ddd, #fff);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #666;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

nav button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1px #bbb inset;
}

nav form {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 2;
  padding: .5rem 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  margin-right: 0;
}

nav form>* {
  margin: 0 .5rem;
}

nav form input {
  align-self: stretch;

  font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  padding: .5rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <img />
  <div>
    <button>XXX</button>
    <form>
      <label>XXX</label>
      <input XXX>
      <div>XXX</div>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

If someone has an idea, a solution... Thanks for helping !

Silvere M.

Comment: Add vendor prefixes of flexbox.what exactly you want to stretch.

Comment: Is anyone really using a version of Chrome that is **30+** versions out of date?

Comment: @MerajKhan Chrome does not need prefix from ver. 29.

Comment: @Paulie_D 0.01% does :)

Comment: I've erased vendor prefixes from the snippet for more lisibility, but it does not work with it neither.

Comment: And the app must be usable with Chrome 30+ browsers. That's in the specs.

Comment: Support browsers 10 versions back is generous, 30 versions is ....

Comment: Does Chrome ver. 31 work?

Comment: Seems to be fixed from Chrome 38. It's really not very big deal for the app itself, but I'd be interested in understanding that issue.

Comment: Even today, in ver. 61, there is _flex bugs or non documented behavior_, so no wonder it doesn't work in a +4 year old version. Furthermore, _form elements_, such as the _button_, has some none standard html behavior and is most likely the reason here.

Comment: OK. Tank you, @LGSon ! Actually, it seems to be the best explanation.